# Symlinks not working on GlusterFS Fuse mount

Tags: centos, glusterfs, symlink, fuse

I am running GlusterFS 3.11.3 on CentOS 7 64-bit in an OpenVZ environment.

Since I am not the datacenter owner and the OpenVZ hosts don't allow sys_admin privileges to virtual machines, I have achieved getting GlusterFS to work via this workaround:
https://serverfault.com/questions/29615/how-to-mount-glusterfs-inside-a-openvz-container

Running

```
find . -regex '.*/[^/]*\.[ch]' -exec sed -i 's/"trusted\./"user./g' {} + \
    && ./configure && make
```

make GlusterFS work in my OpenVZ environment. My provider had to "enable" /dev/fuse additionally which they luckily did for free.

Overall everything worked fine so far, but now I have an installation of SOGo allowing to create sieve rules (SOGo as part of an iRedMail installation). When trying to create a SOGo sieve rule an error occurs and it all turns out to be a problem with creating symlinks on the GlusterFS.

I have mounted a folder this way:

```
eris:/mailrep-volume /var/vmail glusterfs defaults,_netdev 0 0
```

When I try to create a symlink I get an error message

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'dovecot.sieve': Input/output error
```

I have checked all log files but couldn't find any further information about this error.

This error only occurs when I try to create a symbolic link (manually or through a SOGo process) in the /var/vmail mount directory but does not occur when I try to create a symbolic link in the GlusterFS mount dir /mnt/glusterfs/vmail

So, does Fuse not support symbolic links?
Any solutions?

Comment: FUSE supports symlinks, and so does GlusterFS if the underlying storage does.

Comment: @Gilles so where is the problem then? "ln -s" on the GlusterFS FUSE mount does not work.